# Beamer Szeged no navigation dots nor framenumber

Tags: beamer, navigation

I use beamer with the Szeged Theme and I want to have the navigation dots (which normally is the default setting, I guess) and the framenumber in the footer.

My code is the following and I guess I overlook an obvious thing here...but in my output file I have my sections wihtout the dots in the upper part and no framenumber at all.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\footnotesize}
\usetheme{Szeged}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\setbeamercovered{highly dynamic}


\newcounter{saveenumi}
\newcommand{\seti}{\setcounter{saveenumi}{\value{enumi}}}
\newcommand{\conti}{\setcounter{enumi}{\value{saveenumi}}}
\resetcounteronoverlays{saveenumi}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\setbeamercolor*{item}{fg=black}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]


\setbeamertemplate{footline}[framenumber]
\title[]{Title}
\author[]{A:T \inst{1}\\B.T \inst{2}\\  C.A \inst{1}}
\date[]{xx.mm.yyyy}
 \institute[]{\inst{1}Something\\Somewhere\\ \inst{2} Something\\Somewhere}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}


\section{First Section}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Hello}
\textbf{here we go}



\end{frame}
```

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

\usetheme{Szeged}

\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother


\title[sd]{Title}
\author[d]{A:T \inst{1}\\B.T \inst{2}\\  C.A \inst{1}}
\date[sd]{xx.mm.yyyy}
 \institute[]{\inst{1}Something\\Somewhere\\ \inst{2} Something\\Somewhere}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}


\section{First Section}
\subsection{}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Hello}
\textbf{here we go}



\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's how it should look like and the framenumber is also working for me! Still, in my document I only see "First Section" and no dot below....any ideas?

Comment: @KikiRiki See my example, you need a subsection for the dots.